# Make new line after a specific numbers of outputs while printing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, methods

Suppose there is a list;
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Now, if I use print(*a), I'll get

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

But, I want to print it as;

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Here, the key point is making a new line **after specific numbers of outputs**, *not after specific outputs*.

Any built-in functions to achieve this? If not, I'm open to hearing alternative ways.

Comment: Probably not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo operator with integer `3`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in a:
    if i%3:
        print(i, end =" ")
    else:
        print(i)
```

if those integer members are quoted such as `a=['1','2',"3",...]`, then use casting to `int` as by replacing `i%3` with `int(i)%3`

or the members are completely arbitrary string values such as `a = ['1a', '4', "2p", ...]`, then use and index(`j`) for iterayion such as

```
j=0
for i in a:
    j+=1 
    if j%3:
        print(i, end =" ")
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: What if they were not sequenced as they are right now? What if they were strings?

Comment: I meant strings such as "jack", "Rose "......(total 9 of them) @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: recheck out the last edit please @CyberAvater , you can use whatever strings you'd like within the last case.

Comment: Yes, the edited one fills the need but I'll check some more answers. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Ah, So adding [, end =" "] prevents it from making a new line, and then I can style it as I want with coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a bit too special for there to be a general solution in the print function. There is [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) for pretty-printing data structures, but as far as I can see even that does not have this option.

So this might be the shortest way. The function takes n elements from the array and prints them each.

```
from math import ceil


def printN(n, array):
    for i in range(ceil(len(array) / n)):
        print(*array[i*n:(i+1)*n])

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
printN(3, array)
```

Comment: Can you add a full/proper usage example? As you might've guessed I'm a beginner. Thanks!